# Monacaにおけるinappbrowserの挙動について

Tags: monaca

Monacaを用いてiOSとAndroidのハイブリッドアプリを開発しております。外部URLをinappbrowserで開こうとしているのですが、挙動がおかしいです。

```
window.open(href, '_blank');
```

とすると、ちゃんとinappbrowserが起動するのですが、

```
window.open(href, '_self');
```

とすると、inappbrowserが起動はしているのかもしれませんが、通常のinappbrowserではなく、戻るボタン（<）や閉じるボタン（×）が表示されません。つまり、inappbrowserを開いたら、アプリに戻れなくなってしまいます。ちゃんとinappbrowserプラグインも入れています。

引数が `_blank` から `_self` になっただけで起動しなくならなくなるのはなんか変です。

`window.open(href, '_self');` としたときにも、どうすればちゃんとinappbrowserが起動するでしょうか?

Comment: http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_5.2/ja/inappbrowser/

Comment: ところで、何故_selfにしたいのでしょうか。通常のブラウザで別ウィンドウ・別タブで開きたい時にも_blankを指定しますから、こちらの方が自然に見えるのですが。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/29796　マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

基本的には出来ませんが、
`WhiteList`から対象のURLを除外すればCordovaWebViewで開けないので
`InAppBrowser`を強制することが出来るのではないでしょうか？
`InAppBrowser`には開く先をオプションで指定する機能があります。

> - _self: 指定されたURLがWhiteListにある場合CordovaのWebViewで開きます。
>     　　　　それ以外の場合はInAppBrowserで開きます。
> - _blank: `InAppBrowser`で開きます。
> - _system: OSのデフォルトに設定されているWebブラウザーで開きます。

ですが、ブラックリストではないことに注意です。
ホワイトリストですので許可されたURLのみCordovaWebViewからアクセスできます。
初期設定であれば`http`か`https`の接続を全て許可しているかと思います。
外部のサーバに画像を読みに行ったり、Ajaxで通信を行ったりしている場合は設定に要注意です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
CordovaのWebViewで開いてほしいURLと、ajax, jqueryのために
https://ajax.googleapis.com/*
http://code.jquery.com/*
はホワイトリストに追加してみました。
このホワイトリストにないURLのみをinappbrowserで開いてほしいのですが、今度は、URLをタップしても、なにも反応しなくなってしまいました。。。

Comment: module.controller('page1_controller', function($scope) {
                ons.ready(function() {
                    $("#target").load(function(){
                  $("#target").contents().find('a').click(function(){
                            var href = $(this).attr("href");
                            // alert(href);
                            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(href, '_self'); //_self, _block
                            //ref.show();
                        });
                    });
             });
            });

Comment: 3点ほど、1点目、コードなどの追加情報は見づらいので質問文を編集する形で追記してください。2点目、WhiteListの記述の全文を記載してください。聞く限りではWhiteListの項目が足りていません。3点目、質問文へのコメントでunaristさんが訪ねていらっしゃいますがどうでしょうか？`_self`は文字通り現在アクティブなページで自信を上書きして開くのが正しい挙動かと思います。