# InAppBrowserで外部ブラウザ起動しない

Tags: monaca, cordova

お世話になります。
題目通りです。すでに何回か質問されてるようで重複の可能性がありますがよろしくお願いします。

InAppBrowserプラグイン追加しました。

（１）var ref = window.open(url,'_system','location=no');
(2)var ref = window.open(url,'_system','location=yes,hidden=no');
（３）・・・・
（４）・・・・
など考えられるパターンをネットで見つけて手当たり次第試しましたが、一切外部ブラウザで立ち上がりません。WebView内ばかりで表示されます。

現在ベーシック会員だからできないのでしょうか？
そのか設定やJSなどの読み込み、XMLの追加など何かあるのでしょうか？
IDEからの実機デバッグなので実感しないのでしょうか？

全くお手上げ状態です。

大変申し訳御座いませんが御指導願いします。
また重複と思われ不快に感じる方には、この場で陳謝いたします。

追記：はじめてMONACAを使ってます。この場での質問はダメなのでしょうか？それさえも判断がつきません。申し訳御座いません。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: `InAppBrowser`で検索すればたくさんのサンプルコードがあります。よく調べた方がよろしいかと思います。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23136/monaca%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Binappbrowser%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6

Comment: またMonacaのサイトにも記載されています。 https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_5.2/inappbrowser/

Comment: oTakさん
お世話になります。
既に連絡いただいたサイトを含む他サイトのサンプルを真似し かつ 引数など変更し考えられる事を行いました。全て動作しなかったので最後の砦としてここに掲載させていただきました。
どうもダメみたいですね。
お世話になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 試したパターンをすべて記載してください。あと動作環境もお願いします。

Comment: メッセージは対象の回答のコメントに追加してください。追加情報であれば質問文を編集する形で追記してください。誰かへのメッセージは回答として投稿はしないほうが良いです。

Comment: このサイトは「質問と回答」という形に整理することに注力しているので、返信やコメントは質問や回答の下にある「コメント追加」からコメントとして投稿していただけると助かります。また質問が解決した際は回答左側のチェックマークをクリックすると解決済みの目印になります。 よろしければサイトツアーもご覧ください：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @oTak さま。　随分御礼が遅くなった無礼をお許し下さい。やっとこの機能で御礼を届ける事ができると知りました。何度もコメント欄には伝言を書いたのですが、どうも御礼は削除対処だったようです。この場を借りて陳謝いたします。何度も助けていただき感謝しております。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monacaのサイトより抜粋

> `var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);`
>
> target: URL の読み込み先として使用するブラウザーの種別。任意のパラメーターです。デフォルトでは、_self となります。 (String)
>   ・_self: ホワイトリストに対象の URL が登録されている場合には、Cordova WebView を開きます。それ以外の場合には、InAppBrowser を開きます。
>   ・_blank: InAppBrowser を開きます。
>   ・_system: システム標準の Web ブラウザー ( system’s web browser ) を開きます。

`FLEAZ POP(Android 5.1.1)`、`iPhone5(iOS 9.3.1)`の**Monacaデバッガー**で動作確認済みです。
うまく動作しない場合は、動作環境を変えるなどして対応してください。
※スクリーンショットは`Android`。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">

    <script>
        ons.ready(function() {
            console.log("Onsen UI is ready!");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <br>
        <ons-button onclick="window.open('http://ja.stackoverflow.com/', '_self')">_self</ons-button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <ons-button onclick="window.open('http://ja.stackoverflow.com/', '_blank')">_blank</ons-button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <ons-button onclick="window.open('http://ja.stackoverflow.com/', '_system')">_system</ons-button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: oTakさま
早速試したのでご報告いたします。
問題は
ヘッダー内の
＜script src="components/loader.js"＞＜/script＞
を追加してませんでした。
サンプルを読んだようで見逃してたのです。
御迷惑をお掛けした事本当に申し訳ございませんでした。
oTakさまのお陰でアプリの更新も可能となりました。
感謝しております。
本当にありがとうございました。
日中と朝夕の気温差が大きな季節です。
お体に気をつけて下さい。また、私のような未熟なデベロッパーに今後とも指導を願います。
重ね重ね、ありがとうございました。